# Storing values from a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

```
e=[]
rc = RobotControl(robot_name="summit")
def fun (a,b,c):
    for d in a,b,c:
        e.append(d)= rc.get_laser_summit(d)
        print(e)`enter code here`
    


fun(20,200,400)
```

I am really new to python. So I am trying to get value from the get_laser_summit and store it on e. is this the right way to do

Comment: what is ```RobotControl```? And also you cannot iterate over integers ```for d in a,b,c:```.  Perhaps you mean ```for d in zip(a,b,c):```

Comment: For loop always works over iterators but n your case variable  'a,b,c'  are not iterators. S there would be an exception. I think at the place of passing all three of them together you want to pass the list of them but again it depends on your requirement. So, Kindly discribe your question completly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Sujay said you can not iterate over `integer` like 20,200,400 , it is possible they are in list like [20,200,400] , second you `append` function return `None` so you can not assign to it any value , you have to get value then append it

```
e=[]
rc = RobotControl(robot_name="summit")
def fun (lst):
    for d in lst:
        value_from_func = rc.get_laser_summit(d)
        e.append(value_from_func)    
        print(e)


fun([20,200,400]) #[] list can take more a,b,c,d
```

Your code also right but there can be error if list size change so with you code

```
e=[]
rc = RobotControl(robot_name="summit")
def fun (a,b,c):
    for d in a,b,c:
        value_from_fun = rc.get_laser_summit(d)
        e.append(value_from_fun)
        print(e)
    

fun(20,200,400) 
fun(20,200,400,500) # now this will give error
```

if you dont wan't to be list so you can use `*`

```
e=[]
rc = RobotControl(robot_name="summit")
def fun (*lst):
    for d in lst:
        value_from_fun = rc.get_laser_summit(d)
        e.append(value_from_fun)
        print(e)
    

fun(20,200,400)
fun(20,200,400,500) # now this will also work
```

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thanks for the brief explanation. It really saved me.